# RLMException: Cannot add an existing managed embedded object to a List

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm, realm-list

```
Object1: Object
    - id: String
    - title: String
    - items: [Object2]

Object2: EmbeddedObject
    - id: String
    - title: String
    - items: [Object3]

Object3: EmbeddedObject
    - id: String
    - title: String
    - color: String
```

Above is a sample of the schema I have, however, for some odd reason I am consistently getting this error in RealmSwift whenever I try to add `Object1` to the realm.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot add an existing managed embedded object to a List.'
```

Comment: The question is a little vague as we don't know what a lot of those objects are; is `- items: [Object2]` a List or and array or something else? Embedded objects should not have primary keys so what is 'id'? Can you update the question to make it more clear and show us the actual code of the realm objects? Also include the code that's causing the error. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm also facing same issue .. did you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by creating the embedded object outside of a realm.write operation, and then trying to add it to a list from within a write operation.  Everything must be done from within the write operation.

For example, to add a new Object3 into an Object2 you would need to do it like this:

```
try! realm.write {
    let newItem = Object3(id: "someID", title: "Some Title", color: "Some Color")
    object1.items[indexToWrite].items.append(newItem)
}
```

note: Please don't force try a realm write in a real app. :)